# Asus 24" LED VG248QE

Tags: display

I have a Asus 24" LED VG248QE and after I spent the last night at a friends came home and put up my Pc again. Then on accident I switched the power cables from my pc and this monitior. And the colors are distortied, there are white lines going up and down on the screen and its just messed up. What do I do?!

EDIT: Ive been thinking more about it, could it be something else? Maybe it got ruined in the car or something? What do you think.

Comment: You may want to bring a 3rd cable into the mix and see what happens. I agree with ppittle's answer that the cables should be perfectly interchangeable.

Comment: Did you switch them back and still have problems..?

Answer (score 4):

The power cables should be interchangeable between a PC and a Display.

Check to make sure your display cable isn't loose and is still good.  Otherwise it is possible you may have damaged either your video card / port on the PC or the Display.